# The dynamic sub-fields created by JS getting dissapeared after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html

Need some assistance here. I am trying to use HTML to display a form, and JS is there to add a function for adding new subfields by the user.

But my problem is after I am hitting the Save button, the sub-fields which are created dynamically by JavaScript, and their values are getting lost.

It disappeared after I hit the Send button.

Anything I am doing wrong? Any assistance is appreciated.

```
<form method="post" action="">
          <label for="headers">Headers (optional):</label><br>
          <div id="key-value-fields">
              <label for="key1">Key:</label>
              <input type="text" id="key1" name="key1" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['key1'])) { echo $_POST['key1']; } ?>">
              <label for="value1">Value:</label>
              <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['value1'])) { echo $_POST['value1']; } ?>">
          </div>
          <button type="button" id="add-another" onclick="addKeyValueField()">Add another</button>
          <input type="submit" value="Send Request">
       </form>
<script>
          var fieldIndex = 2;
          function addKeyValueField() {
              var keyValueFields = document.getElementById('key-value-fields');
              var newFields = document.createElement('div');
              newFields.innerHTML = '<label for="key' + fieldIndex + '">Key:</label> <input type="text" id="key' + fieldIndex + '" name="key' + fieldIndex + '"> <label for="value' + fieldIndex + '">Value:</label> <input type="text" id="value' + fieldIndex + '" name="value' + fieldIndex + '"> <button type="button" onclick="deleteKeyValueField(this)">Delete</button>';
              keyValueFields.appendChild(newFields);
              fieldIndex++;
          }
          function deleteKeyValueField(button) {
              var keyValueField = button.parentElement;
              keyValueField.remove();
          }
</script>
```

### Updated:

```
<form method="post" action="">
     <label for="headers">Headers (optional):</label><br>
     <div id="key-value-fields">
       <label for="key1">Key:</label>
       <input type="text" id="key1" name="key[]" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['key'][0])) { echo $_POST['key'][0]; } ?>">
       <label for="value1">Value:</label>
       <input type="text" id="value1" name="value[]" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['value'][0])) { echo $_POST['value'][0]; } ?>">
     </div>
     <button type="button" id="add-another" onclick="addKeyValueField()">Add another</button>
     <input type="submit" value="Send Request">
   </form>

   <?php
     for ($fieldIndex = 0; isset($_POST['key' . $fieldIndex]); $fieldIndex++) {
   ?>
     <label for="key<?php echo $fieldIndex; ?>">Key:</label>
     <input type="text" id="key<?php echo $fieldIndex; ?>" name="key<?php echo $fieldIndex; ?>" value="<?php echo $_POST["key"][$fieldIndex] ?>">
     <label for="value<?php echo $fieldIndex; ?>">Value:</label>
     <input type="text" id="value<?php echo $fieldIndex; ?>" name="value<?php echo $fieldIndex; ?>" value="<?php echo $_POST["value"][$fieldIndex] ?>">
     <button type="button" onclick="deleteKeyValueField(this)">Delete</button>
   <?php
     }
   ?>

   <script>
     var fieldIndex = 2;
     function addKeyValueField() {
       var keyValueFields = document.getElementById('key-value-fields');
       var newFields = document.createElement('div');
       
       newFields.innerHTML = '<label for="key' + fieldIndex + '">Key:</label> <input type="text" id="key' + fieldIndex + '" name="key[]"> <label for="value' + fieldIndex + '">Value:</label> <input type="text" id="value' + fieldIndex + '" name="value[]"> <button type="button" onclick="deleteKeyValueField(this)">Delete</button>';
       keyValueFields.appendChild(newFields);
       fieldIndex++;
     }
     function deleteKeyValueField(button) {
       var keyValueField = button.parentElement;
       keyValueField.remove();
     }
   </script>
```

Comment: you are may be loading your page try event.preventDefault() in your JS

Comment: I tried to add the form submission code inside a event listener function, after calling event.preventDefault(). Not working still :/

Answer (score 0):

You have a `form` tag and a `submit` action is triggered. This means that your form's fields (particularly those which have a `name`) are being sent to your server. Your server handles the request and sends back some content to your browser.

You have sent your new fields along with their values and your server received them, but your server did not render them back. On your server you could do something like this:

```
for ($fieldIndex = 2; isset($_POST['key'.$fieldIndex]); $fieldIndex++) {
?>
<label for="key<?php echo fieldIndex; ?>">Key:</label>
<input type="text" id="key<?php echo fieldIndex; ?>" name="key<?php echo fieldIndex; ?>" value="<?php echo $_POST["key" . $fieldIndex] ?>">
<label for="value<?php echo fieldIndex; ?>">Value:</label>
<input type="text" id="value<?php echo fieldIndex; ?>" name="value<?php echo fieldIndex; ?>" value="<?php echo $_POST["name" . $fieldIndex] ?>">
<button type="button" onclick="deleteKeyValueField(this)">Delete</button>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But didn't work, still the same :/

Comment: @TECHFREEKS can you edit your question with your PHP code? Currently we are speaking about a bug that you have in your PHP code without seeing it.

Comment: @TECHFREEKS you have a typo in your for cycle, replace `isset($_POST['key'][$fieldIndex])` with `isset($_POST['key' . $fieldIndex])`.

Comment: Thanks for the sharp eye on that. But, unfortunately, that didn't solve the issue. :/

Comment: @TECHFREEKS understood. How is the error manifesting now? Do you create (at least ) a new field after you load the page, submit the form and then the form is refreshed without the field? If not, then how else is it not working? Thanks!

Comment: @TECHFREEKS wait a minute, you start with a non-zero index. Let me adjust the suggestion.

Comment: @TECHFREEKS is it better now?

Comment: Thanks. But that didn't work either. Okay, no what is happening is I can add new dynamic fields by clicking "Add Another". I can also delete the newly created dynamic fields. But, after I enter some value, and hit on "Send" on the form, the newly created dynamic fields vanishes. But the initial one stays, along with its values. The newly created dynamic fields are going away after submitting the form.

Comment: @TECHFREEKS first question: Do you get an error? Second question: If you do an `echo json_encode($_POST)`, can you tell me the results of that (after you submitted)?

Comment: Sure. Firstly, Nope, there is no such errors. I checked the console, and there was no error related to JS. And secondly, I tried to echo json_encode($_POST["key"]) and echo json_encode($_POST["value"]). It appears that the value is getting sent perfectly. But the new fields re just getting vanished. The data is being sent, but the new dynamically created fields along with their data are getting lost.

Comment: @TECHFREEKS I mean: are there PHP errors in your server log? Secondly: I need to see your `$_POST`'s content in order to determine what's wrong.